# Is there a non-final field in Java SE 6 or Java SE 7

Tags: java, field, final, mutable

Is there anywhere in any of the classes of SE 6 or SE 7 a field which is not final, i.e. which can be set directly?

I am working on bindings from another language (Haskell) to Java and I am seeking for that specific case to check whether my implementation works correctly.

I am not interested in a discussion about whether one should access fields directly or not (my bindings generate getters and setters anyway since there are only functions in Haskell).

So: do you know of any non-final, static or non-static field in any of the classes in the java standard library?

Comment: You ask about two different things: "not final" and "can be set directly". Non-final fields are extremely common in the API classes. Did you mean "public", which is what you would need to be able to set a field directly from an unrelated class?

Comment: Yes, of course I was only talking about public members.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
java.awt.Dimension.height
java.awt.Dimension.width
java.awt.Event.arg
java.awt.Event.clickCount
java.awt.Event.evt
java.awt.Event.id
java.awt.Event.key
java.awt.Event.modifiers
java.awt.Event.target
java.awt.Event.when
java.awt.Event.x
java.awt.Event.y
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.anchor
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.fill
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.gridheight
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.gridwidth
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.gridx
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.gridy
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.insets
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.ipadx
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.ipady
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.weightx
java.awt.GridBagConstraints.weighty
java.awt.GridBagLayout.columnWeights
java.awt.GridBagLayout.columnWidths
java.awt.GridBagLayout.rowHeights
java.awt.GridBagLayout.rowWeights
java.awt.Insets.bottom
java.awt.Insets.left
java.awt.Insets.right
java.awt.Insets.top
java.awt.Point.x
java.awt.Point.y
java.awt.Polygon.npoints
java.awt.Polygon.xpoints
java.awt.Polygon.ypoints
java.awt.Rectangle.height
java.awt.Rectangle.width
java.awt.Rectangle.x
java.awt.Rectangle.y
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Double.extent
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Double.height
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Double.start
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Double.width
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Double.x
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Double.y
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.extent
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.height
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.start
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.width
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.x
java.awt.geom.Arc2D$Float.y
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.ctrlx1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.ctrlx2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.ctrly1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.ctrly2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.x1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.x2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.y1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Double.y2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.ctrlx1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.ctrlx2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.ctrly1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.ctrly2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.x1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.x2
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.y1
java.awt.geom.CubicCurve2D$Float.y2
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Double.height
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Double.width
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Double.x
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Double.y
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float.height
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float.width
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float.x
java.awt.geom.Ellipse2D$Float.y
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double.x1
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double.x2
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double.y1
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Double.y2
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Float.x1
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Float.x2
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Float.y1
java.awt.geom.Line2D$Float.y2
java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double.x
java.awt.geom.Point2D$Double.y
java.awt.geom.Point2D$Float.x
java.awt.geom.Point2D$Float.y
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Double.ctrlx
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Double.ctrly
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Double.x1
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Double.x2
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Double.y1
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Double.y2
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Float.ctrlx
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Float.ctrly
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Float.x1
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Float.x2
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Float.y1
java.awt.geom.QuadCurve2D$Float.y2
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double.height
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double.width
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double.x
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Double.y
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float.height
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float.width
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float.x
java.awt.geom.Rectangle2D$Float.y
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Double.archeight
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Double.arcwidth
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Double.height
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Double.width
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Double.x
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Double.y
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float.archeight
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float.arcwidth
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float.height
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float.width
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float.x
java.awt.geom.RoundRectangle2D$Float.y
java.beans.beancontext.BeanContextChildSupport.beanContextChildPeer
java.io.InterruptedIOException.bytesTransferred
java.io.InvalidClassException.classname
java.io.OptionalDataException.eof
java.io.OptionalDataException.length
java.io.StreamTokenizer.nval
java.io.StreamTokenizer.sval
java.io.StreamTokenizer.ttype
java.io.WriteAbortedException.detail
java.rmi.RemoteException.detail
java.rmi.activation.ActivationException.detail
java.rmi.server.ServerCloneException.detail
java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo.choices
java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo.description
java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo.name
java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo.required
java.sql.DriverPropertyInfo.value
javax.accessibility.AccessibleAttributeSequence.attributes
javax.accessibility.AccessibleAttributeSequence.endIndex
javax.accessibility.AccessibleAttributeSequence.startIndex
javax.accessibility.AccessibleTextSequence.endIndex
javax.accessibility.AccessibleTextSequence.startIndex
javax.accessibility.AccessibleTextSequence.text
javax.sound.midi.VoiceStatus.active
javax.sound.midi.VoiceStatus.bank
javax.sound.midi.VoiceStatus.channel
javax.sound.midi.VoiceStatus.note
javax.sound.midi.VoiceStatus.program
javax.sound.midi.VoiceStatus.volume
javax.swing.SizeRequirements.alignment
javax.swing.SizeRequirements.maximum
javax.swing.SizeRequirements.minimum
javax.swing.SizeRequirements.preferred
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$ChangeHandler.isSelected
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$ChangeHandler.menu
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$ChangeHandler.ui
javax.swing.plaf.basic.BasicMenuUI$ChangeHandler.wasFocused
javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$KeyBinding.actionName
javax.swing.text.JTextComponent$KeyBinding.key
javax.swing.text.Segment.array
javax.swing.text.Segment.count
javax.swing.text.Segment.offset
javax.swing.text.html.parser.AttributeList.modifier
javax.swing.text.html.parser.AttributeList.name
javax.swing.text.html.parser.AttributeList.next
javax.swing.text.html.parser.AttributeList.type
javax.swing.text.html.parser.AttributeList.value
javax.swing.text.html.parser.AttributeList.values
javax.swing.text.html.parser.ContentModel.content
javax.swing.text.html.parser.ContentModel.next
javax.swing.text.html.parser.ContentModel.type
javax.swing.text.html.parser.DTD.elementHash
javax.swing.text.html.parser.DTD.elements
javax.swing.text.html.parser.DTD.entityHash
javax.swing.text.html.parser.DTD.name
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.atts
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.content
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.data
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.exclusions
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.inclusions
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.index
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.name
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.oEnd
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.oStart
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Element.type
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity.data
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity.name
javax.swing.text.html.parser.Entity.type
javax.transaction.xa.XAException.errorCode
javax.xml.ws.Holder.value
```

Some of them are clearly WTFs.

Answer (score 3):

Look at some of the geometry types in `java.awt` package, like the `x` and `y` fields of [`Point`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/awt/Point.html).